# Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException; Route [home.getstarted] not defined

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am new to web development and I am doing this as my project. Your help in solving this will go a long way.

I am getting this route error on 4 of my blade PHP code. The first error comes in line:429. How do I correct it?

```
  ** * Get the URL to a named route.

 *

 * @param  string  $name

 * @param  mixed  $parameters

 * @param  bool  $absolute

 * @return string

 *

 * @throws \Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException

 */

public function route($name, $parameters = [], $absolute = true)

{

    if (! is_null($route = $this->routes->getByName($name))) {

        return $this->toRoute($route, $parameters, $absolute);

    }



    throw new RouteNotFoundException("Route [{$name}] not defined.");

}



/**

 * Get the URL for a given route instance.

 *

 * @param  \Illuminate\Routing\Route  $route

 * @param  mixed  $parameters

 * @param  bool  $absolute

 * @return string

 *

 * @throws \Illuminate\Routing\Exceptions\UrlGenerationException

 */

public function toRoute($route, $parameters, $absolute)

{

    $parameters = collect(Arr::wrap($parameters))->map(function ($value, $key) use ($route) {**
```

here is the second PHP code with the error here: `<form action="{{ route('home.getstarted') }}" method="post" class="getStartedForm">`

```
</nav>

                    </div>

                    <div class="input-section recepiet">

                        <div class="money-input-field">

                            <input type="number" id="final_amount" placeholder="83,876">

                            <span>{{ __('Recipient Gets') }}</span>

                        </div>

                        <div class="money-currency">

                            <a href="#" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><span><img id="country_flag" src="" alt=""> <span id="currency_name"> </span>&nbsp <span class="iconify" data-icon="dashicons:arrow-down-alt2" data-inline="fa

                            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end currency" id="currencyList">

                            </ul>

                            <input type="hidden" name="currency_name" id="currency_symbol">

                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="calculation-checkout-btn">

                        <form action="{{ route('home.getstarted') }}" method="post" class="getStartedForm">

                            @csrf

                            <input type="hidden" value="" name="charge">

                            <input type="hidden" value="" name="currency">

                            <input type="hidden" value="" name="amount">

                            <input type="hidden" value="" name="withdrawmethod">

                            <button type="submit" id="getStarted">{{ __('Get Started') }}</button>

                        </form>


                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

The third PHP code, the error came in line 25

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Localization

{

    /**

     * Handle an incoming request.

     *

     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request

     * @param  \Closure  $next

     * @return mixed

     */

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)

    {

        if (\Session::has('locale')==true) {

            \App::setlocale(\Session::get('locale'));

        }

        else{

            \Session::put('locale',env('DEFAULT_LANG','en'));

            \App::setlocale(\Session::get('locale'));

        }

        return $next($request);

    }

}
```

the Forth PHP code with error in `$request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()`. Below is the code:

```
    | We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.

| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it

| will load up this application so that we can run it and send

| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.

|

*/

 

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/script/bootstrap/app.php';

 

/*

|--------------------------------------------------------------------------

| Run The Application

|--------------------------------------------------------------------------

|

| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request

| through the kernel, and send the associated response back to

| the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative

| and wonderful application we have prepared for them.

|

*/

 

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

 

$response = $kernel->handle(

    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()

);

 

$response->send();

 

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

What can be done to remedy this error?

Comment: Can you show your route file?

Answer (score 1):

Just Open the Terminal and change directory to same project folder location then type:

```
php artisan route:cache
```

All new routes will be cached and new routes will be accessible

Comment: Can you please explain more as I am finding it difficult to understand what this means " Open the Terminal and change directory to same project folder location ".

Comment: Simply Open Project folder in explorer in the directory tab up double click then full path to project will show delete it then type cmd after then use the command